# Standard way to add headers to ListView in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

Is there a simple way to add Section headers to a list view. I've done a custom one, but it makes it much more difficult to detect which row that is getting selected.

Comment: It seems as there is no standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem be be a default way to approach this. The easiest way is to create a custom adapter. UITableViews in iOS really is a better implementation :s